# Excel screws up my dates when system is set to European date format

Tags: excel, vba

Here's what I'm doing: 
1. In Control Panel I set up the system date format as follows: dd/MM/yyyy
2. I create the following simple macro:

```
Sub hello()
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "10/01/2014"
End Sub
```

1. I run it, and get the following date in the cell (1,1): 01/10/2014

Whenever the date is less then 12 it converts the date to american format (MM/dd/yyyy), and when the date is more than 12 it fails to convert it and writes the date in the cell correctly, but as text.
I first discovered this when trying to write dates from VSTO, but then narrowed it down to any place where you write a date to a cell from code, even Macros.
Is that an Excel bug or am I doing something wrong? I'm using Excel 2013, but I believe this problem exists in all other versions as well...

Comment: Aside: *sigh*. `YYYY-MM-DD` has been a standard representation that avoids mm/dd or dd/mm confusion, for 48 years http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_2014

Comment: Thanks! you got me on the right track!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA considers all date literals to be in US format *unless the literal cannot possibly be a valid US-formatted date*.  If you use `"10/Jan/2014"` (or `#10/Jan/2014#`; the `#`s are date literal markers), VBA will fall back to dd/MMM/yyyy since it can't be anything else.

If you need VBA to understand your local date format, use:

```
Sub hello()
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = DateValue("10/01/2014")
End Sub
```

...since (as stated in the VBA Help files):

> `DateValue` recognizes the order for month, day, and year according to
>   the Short Date format you specified for your system. DateValue also
>   recognizes unambiguous dates that contain month names, either in long
>   or abbreviated form.

So, as long as your PC has the correct locale set, `DateValue()` should understand your preferred date format.

Comment: Thanks, this solves it VBA! My problem, however, is not in VBA, but in VSTO, I'm writing dates to a range of cells using Range.set_Values(array) method. Is there a way to use something similar to DateValue() in C# code?

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx for the DateTime constructors and `Parse` or `ParseExact`.

Comment: M$ is incredible !