# Vlookup Dates in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with **3 excel sheets**.  In **sheet Start Page** i have **Dates starting from column A4** going down. The macro Vlooks up in sheet **Fund Trend** for the same Dates which are locate in column **A11 to lastrow** and offsets 3 columns , and copies the Value into sheet **"Accrued Expenses"** starting from **Range("C7")**. Macro **loops until** the lastrow in sheets("Start page") Range("A4") .

**The Problem** is that the macro is not populating the values into sheet Accrued expenses, on some occasions. **OR** its not finding the Date.  My code is below:

```
Sub NetAsset_Value()
Dim result As Double
Dim Nav_Date As Worksheet
Dim fund_Trend As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set Nav_Date = Sheets("Start page")
Set fund_Trend = Sheets("Fund Trend")
lRow = Sheets("Start page").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

 For i = 4 To lRow



result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Nav_Date.Range("A" & i), fund_Trend.Range("A11:C1544"), 3, False)

            Sheets("Accrued Expenses").Range("C" & i + 3).Value = result
             Sheets("Accrued Expenses").Range("C" & i + 3).NumberFormat = "0.00"
         Sheets("Accrued Expenses").Range("C" & i + 3).Style = "Comma"




    Next i

End Sub
```

Error Trap:

```
On Error Resume Next

result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Nav_Date.Range("A" & i), fund_Trend.Range("A11:C1544"), 3, False)

        If Err.Number = 0 Then

            Sheets("Accrued Expenses").Range("C" & i + 3).Value = result
             Sheets("Accrued Expenses").Range("C" & i + 3).NumberFormat = "0.00"
         Sheets("Accrued Expenses").Range("C" & i + 3).Style = "Comma"
        End If


        On Error GoTo 0
```

To over come the Date issue i have this sub dont know if this is efficient?

```
Sub dates()
Sheets("Start page").Range("A4", "A50000").NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
Sheets("Fund Trend").Range("A11", "A50000").NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
End Sub
```

The issue that i am now having is that when enter a date like 11/02/2015 it switches to 02/11/2015. But its not happening to all Dates

**Overcoming the Problem.** I am placed a worksheet function to force the date columns to text. Which is currently working.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Sheets("Start page").Range("A4", "A50000").NumberFormat = "@"
Sheets("Fund Trend").Range("A11", "A50000").NumberFormat = "@"
End Sub
```

Comment: Are they valid dates and is the regional settings consistent with what is in the columns?

Comment: You've described two problems, which are kind of different. On one hand, you say it's not returning a result value -- did you debug this? What is the `result` in these instances? If there is an error, it should raise appropriately using the `WorksheetFunction` class. If the date isn't found, then that is certainly a 1004 error.  You can get around that with some error trapping, but first look in to @AnthonyHorne suggestion.

Comment: @AnthonyHome when the macro runs , it gets data from an external system. i have been trying to standardize the dates in both sheets.

Comment: It's getting data from the Excel worksheet. Now, that may be *coming from* an external system at some earlier time, but at run-time, it's part of the Excel worksheet (even if it's a formula API returning data from an external source), and not from another system.

Comment: @DavidZemens i am getting a runtime error 1004 of - unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheet function class. However i worked myself around this with an error trap. But no values .

Comment: show the code of your error trap? Update your original quesiton to include the current code.

Comment: That's not an error trap :) that's an *error-ignorer*.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the 1004 error you can use the `Application.VLookup` function, which allows an error type as a return value.  Use this method to test for an error, and if no error, return the result.

To do this, you'll have to `Dim result as Variant` since (in this example) I put a text/string value in the `result` to help identify the error occurrences.

```
If IsError(Application.Vlookup(Nav_Date.Range("A" & i), fund_Trend.Range("A11:C1544"), 3, False)) Then
    result = "date not found!"
Else
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Nav_Date.Range("A" & i), fund_Trend.Range("A11:C1544"), 3, False)
End If
```

The "no result printed in the worksheet" needs further debugging on your end. Have you stepped through the code to ensure that the `result` is what you expect it to be, for any given lookup value? If there is no error, then what is almost **certainly** happening is that the formula you have entered is returning a null string and that value is being put in the cell.

Comment: No error is being returned . perfect. The reason why data is not found  i think its the date type in the sheets is different . I need to find a way around this.

Comment: But you still need to debug what the `result` is when "no error is returned", because if no error raises, then the date **IS** found, and that suggests something wrong with your formula, if you're expecting a return value.

Comment: Now, the dates may also be in a different format that could be causing some of those 1004/not found erros, but that's another issue altogether. If the result is a null string, you need to debug and find out *why*, because that is **not** an error in the code, it's an error in your logic, which I won't be able to debug without examples of the data.

Comment: I am working on formatting the dates in both sheets to be the same , and incorporate it in my code

Comment: the date formats are different , i think that's definitely the issue i think. i am trying to code it that before the vlookup runs the two columns are formatted that same.

Comment: That will certainly do the formatting I just don't know if the formatting is the problem or the format is the problem. if these dates are coming from an external system that does not use the same system locale you're going to have issues

Comment: The issue that i am now having is that when enter a date like 11/02/2015 it switches to 02/11/2015. But its not happening to all Dates

Comment: Do you expect that date to be February 11th or November 2nd?

Comment: 11th February 2015 this will cause an issue

Comment: Yeah that will be an issue. how are these dates being inserted to the work book?

Comment: In the start sheet there are being inserted manually by the user.The dates being enter by user are switching to  02/11/2015.

Comment: Previously you said they're coming from an external system -- can you clarify? There's a lot of issues with Excel attempting to interpret "dates" especially when they are not in the same locale. They can all be resolved but right now is not really clear to me what the problem source actually is.

Comment: The worksheet called "Fund trend" gets information from an external system. The worksheet called  "Start page" the user enters the dates to be vlooked up in the Fund trend sheet

Comment: How are they arriving from the external system?  And, please answer re the system locale ..

Comment: my system locale is usa region. however when the macro is run the user 98% always puts in English (uk) standard date 11/02/2015.

Comment: OK, and I think that VBA always attempts to interpret dates in US English, so 2/11 is February 11, not November 2, and 13/3 can't be parsed as a date at all... I've dealt with this US/UK issue before and it nearly drove me crazy...  you may have better luck treating the values as text -- this may mean adjusting whatever your import process is (you still haven't answered that Q --- **how does the data arrive in Fund Trend sheet**?) to explicitly treat that data as text.

Comment: when the data is pull from the system  arrives in the format of text . IS this what you asking

Comment: No, I'm asking **by what procedure** does the data arrive? Are you using query tables? formula/API? Something else?

Comment: Some background info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468187/excel-screws-up-my-dates-when-system-is-set-to-european-date-format/22468400#22468400

Comment: I am using an IO OLE connection to download data . I have actually put a worksheet function to set my column dates as text. This seems to me be working . Need to run a couple of trails on it first.

Comment: yeah if you force it to text in both places, and then do a lookup against the text, I think that will work.

Comment: You can add an "answer" to your own question, too :)

Comment: I eventually answered my own question ha thanks to you